# How an embeded image be sent from an Android email client?

Tags: android

I have to embed an image from SD card in the email and send it.I am trying with HTML tags but its not working.can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will help you

```
 File myDir=new File("/sdcard/Download");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    String fname = "Image.jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir,fname);
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        // finalBitmap means sending image.
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("Image/jpg");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Greetings");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Hi");
        File downloadedPic = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                             (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"image.jpg");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(downloadedPic));
        Full.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "send"));
    } catch (Exception e) {}
```